# comparing c++ string

Tags: c++, string, compare

```
class Song {

public:
    const string getAutherName();
}

void mtm::RadioManager::addSong(const Song& song,const Song& song1) {

    if (song.getAutherName() == song1.getAutherName())

}
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> getAutherName() ' - passing 'const mtm::Song' as 'this' argument of 'std::string mtm::Song::getAutherName()' discards qualifiers [- fpermissive]
```

Why is it using `basic_string` and not `string`! how to fix this?

Comment: `std::basic_string<...` just is the actual thing used in the background. The error is still about your usage of `std::string`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - this is C++, `==` is overloaded and allows for string equality comparisons.

Comment: @MarounMaroun this is `c++` not java

Comment: sorry.. I didn't notice that :)

Comment: in which function call do you get the error?

Comment: `std::string` is just a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char>`

Comment: Try post your Song header

Comment: Please copy the exact error message, what you have there looks strange. Also `getAutherName()`  isn't const, you can't call with those Song references AFAICT.

Comment: Also, Christine - your code is incomplete (the class declaration doesn't even end with a `;` and your `if` statement doesn't terminate). You might be missing a header file, but if this is the entirety of your code, it will be hard for us to help you.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> 
  getAutherName() '
 - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> 
  getAutherName() '
 - passing 'const mtm::Song' as 'this' argument of 'std::string mtm::Song::getAutherName()' discards qualifiers [-
  fpermissive]

Comment: @Christine: just edit you original question - provide some more code, please. Ideally enough to throw it at the compiler and get the same errors you get. Chrystal balls and magic mirrors are hard to find these days ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your `getAutherName()` function is not `const`, so it cannot be called through a `const Song&`. Change the function declaration like this:

```
class Song {

public:
    const string getAutherName() const;
}
```

Comment: Also, it should probably be returning const string &.

Comment: @Steve Depends on whether the string is stored or computed. With C++11's move semantics, I'd be more inklined to return just `string`. Not `const string`, though.

Comment: I'd guess that it's returning a private member so the copy in the return can't be elided (I think) so a reference is likely better in this case. But yeah, just const string is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `getAutherName()` on const `Songs` so you need to make that method `const`:

```
const string getAutherName() const;
```

It isn't clear why you return a `const string`. Either return a `string`, or return a const reference to one:

```
const string& getAutherName() const;
string getAutherName() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a typedef for `basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`, the compiler is just expanding the typedef in the error message.

However, why the code is not working I don't know. You appear to have cut out part of your error message where the ' is.

Comment: Odd, but as others have said, the problem is the method not being declared as const.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `const` qualification to `getAutherName` to allow it to be called on const `Song` objects:

```
//| -- Returns a `const` `string` (this is bad practice
//v    because it inhibits optimization)
const string getAutherName() const;
// Can be called on a `const`    ^
// `Song`. This is good practice |
// because it it allows `getAutherName()`
// to be used in more places, and it encourages
// const-correctness.
```